# Banno Admin API for External Transfers

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I am having an issue calling External Transfer Settings API. I tested other APIs and was able to get a response. Below is the URI I used for External Transfers.

https://banno.com/a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/xxxx/xxxxxxx/transfer/settings/external
and the response I got is 'Cannot PUT /a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/xxxx/xxxxx/transfer/settings/external'

Answer (score 0):

##### 1) Which endpoint is the the one that is failing?

The `/xxxx/xxxxx/` makes it a bit ambiguous if this is the **Institution External Transfer Settings** endpoint (`PUT /a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/transfer/settings/external` or if it is the **User External Transfer Settings** endpoint (`PUT /a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/transfer/settings/external`

##### 2) Can you provide the full error response?

The error response will have an HTTP status code (which is helpful), a response body, and a header `x-request-id` (which is also helpful) to understand what is occurring.

Comment: Thank you. 1) It is the User External Transfer Settings that is failing. (PUT /a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/transfer/settings/external.                     2)Status code 404 Not Found, Response body: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
 <pre>Cannot PUT /a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/xxxx/xxxx/transfer/settings/external</pre>
</body>

</html>  and header:

Comment: header x-request-id is not available in the response

Comment: A common reason for getting an `HTTP 404 Not Found` is due to the URL construction. In this case, the `/a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/xxxx/xxxx/transfer/settings/external` pattern doesn't match the *User External Transfer Settings* pattern. If I were to use `xxxx` as a placeholder for `institutionId` and `userId`, then the URL pattern would be `/a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/xxxx/users/xxxx/transfer/settings/external`. Can you confirm the URL that you are using? Because it seems like there may be a mismatch (speculation based on what I see in your comment).

Comment: Yes, I am using /a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/xxxx/users/xxxx/transfer/settings/external URL pattern. Sorry, typo in my previous comment. I tested all four URIs External, Internal transfer settings for Institution, Users and none of them are working. All responding with HTTP 404 Not Found.  I used same institution id and user id for testing other APIs and they are responding with the json data.

Comment: We'll have to check with the Engineering team on the topic. In the meantime, do you have the Institution ID available to share? That may be helpful if the issue turns out to be institution-specific.

Comment: Thank you. Our institution ID is 4241.

Comment: Ah, I see. That _technically_ isn't the `Institution ID` (which is in UUID format) but instead what is often referred to as the `short ID` (for an institution). The API docs admittedly are ambiguous, but the Admin API expects to have callers use the UUID form of your Institution ID.

Comment: I tried using UUID form of my Institution ID but still no luck. Cannot PUT /a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/78121b95-45c1-47ba-b4da-8e8892440b00/users/f2cc5fa2-d136-43ec-b419-c7e5a1b66e53/transfer/settings/external

Comment: Looks like I get an HTTP 404 as well. Checking with Engineering. HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2022 15:01:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Vary: Accept-Encoding

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot PUT /a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/899f4398-106d-409a-9ed4-a72346778076/users/e58dc9d6-0acb-4770-b719-93fe675f652b/transfer/settings/external</pre>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Can you try again? Engineering deployed a fix and I'm now successful using this redacted example: curl --request PUT \
  --url https://banno.com/a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/transfer/settings/external \
  --header 'authorization: [My-Access-Token]' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{"dailyOutboundLimit": 1}' ---> which gives me a response of HTTP 204 No Content

Comment: Thank you, seems like API is working but responding with errorcode :40   with HTTP 403 status          
 Response Headers                                                                                                       Date: Thu, 14 Apr 2022 02:09:54 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 16
Connection: keep-alive
x-request-id: bf90ffd5e97311ae034166e2fd77f7d4
x-b3-traceid: f8eef31ab640371b
x-b3-spanid: f8eef31ab640371b
x-b3-sampled: 1
ETag: W/"10-tOwpq784DuRtH0XE2ycaKfLBS+A"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800
Response Body
{"errorCode":40}

Comment: The HTTP 403 Forbidden is a 'good' change in the behavior, since that tells us that you no longer get a 404 Not Found so the API is reachable. It's difficult to tell if you were successful in retrieving an Access Token, but let's assume that you did. If you have a valid Access Token but still get the HTTP 403, it's likely that you need to make sure that the Associated User (https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/overview/authentication/associateduser/) has permissions to use the endpoint. That's likely "Manage [internal/external] transfers", depending upon the API endpoint.

Comment: I am getting HTTP 500 error now. Per documentation, the issue is with Officer code.

500 Internal Server Error (Officer code not defined)
Media type: application/json
Example Value
Schema
"Officer code not defined"

Comment: Clarification question: the documentation _does_ describe an _example_ of "Officer code not defined" but that is a single example and doesn't describe _all_ possible causes of the HTTP 500 error. What additional text did you get with the HTTP 500 error? That'll be helpful for us to pass along to Engineering.

Comment: It is not showing any text in the response. Response Headers: Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 14:27:22 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
x-request-id: baf03edef46d718ef36b1ac6dc76c3cc
x-b3-traceid: 66b0fc8422ccaeaa
x-b3-spanid: 66b0fc8422ccaeaa
x-b3-sampled: 1
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 22
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800                                                                       Response body: ∅

Comment: Originally, you were trying to use the `PUT /a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/transfer/settings/external` endpoint.

Now it appears you're trying to use the `PUT /a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/transfer/settings/external` endpoint. In that case, please notice that the endpoints have *required* and *optional* attributes defined in the docs. For this specific endpoint for Institution External Transfer settings, the `cutOffTime` attribute is required in the request.

Comment: Thank you. PUT /a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/transfer/settings/external to update user limits is working fine. PUT /a/transfer-settings/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/transfer/settings/external endpoint to update institution settings still throwing HTTP 500 error. I tried adding cutOffTime but it did not work.

Comment: Request Body
{
  "inboundDailyQuantitativeLimit": 42,
  "outboundDailyQuantitativeLimit": 42,
  "cutOffTime": "61200",
  "inboundHighRiskThreshold": 100,
  "outboundHighRiskThreshold": 100
}
Response Headers
Date: Sat, 23 Apr 2022 02:50:01 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
x-request-id: 68de5787c7943dbe384b42cdb05362af
x-b3-traceid: ecd2cebe720154f5
x-b3-spanid: ecd2cebe720154f5
x-b3-sampled: 1
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 15
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800
Response Body ∅

Comment: Ah, that's helpful. It turns out we had a problem with the rendering of the docs, which showed "61200" instead of the "17:00:00" intended for the example of `cutOffTime`. The format is `hh:mm:ss` but a typo in the spec file caused the rendering to break. You might have to force a browser refresh of the docs page to see the change.

Comment: Thank you so much. API responded with HTTP 204 after changing cutOffTime.

Comment: Excellent, glad it's working for you. Thanks for bearing with us.